# asp.net mvc return view pagedlist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

I have below actionresult

```
 public ActionResult TheMostClickedEmailReport(int ID, int gonderim,int? page)
        {
            int pageIndex = page ?? 1;
            int pagesize = 10;

            MailingClickService mailingclickservice = new MailingClickService();
            TemplateLinkService tmpservice = new TemplateLinkService();
            int FirmID = (int)Session["FirmID"];
            var linkler = mailingclickservice.GetByCriteria(x => x.MailingID == ID && x.Gonderim == gonderim && x.Mailing.FirmUser.FirmID == FirmID).IslemSonucu.GroupBy(x => x.MailingEmail).ToPagedList(pageIndex, pagesize);



            ViewBag.gonderim = gonderim;
            ViewBag.MailingID = ID;

            List<EmailLinkClickReport> emailcliklistreport = new List<EmailLinkClickReport>();
            if (linkler.Count() > 0)
            {

                foreach (var item in linkler)
                {
                    EmailLinkClickReport emaillinkclick = new EmailLinkClickReport();

                    emaillinkclick.Key = item.Key;
                    emaillinkclick.TotalClicksCount = item.Select(x => x.MailingEmail).Count();
                    emailcliklistreport.Add(emaillinkclick);
                }


                return View(emailcliklistreport);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("MailingReport", "Report", new { id = ID, gonderim = gonderim });
            }
        }
```

**linkler** has 50 data.I select 10 data from **linkler** by using **foreach (item in linkler)**

I want to select 10 data in v`ar linkler = mailingclickservice.GetByCriteria(x => x.MailingID == ID && x.Gonderim == gonderim && x.Mailing.FirmUser.FirmID == FirmID).IslemSonucu.GroupBy(x => x.MailingEmail).ToPagedList(pageIndex, pagesize);` 
part

however  i do not know how can i cast linkler to IPagedList by returning view ?

If i return below  code

```
return View(emailcliklistreport);
```

like below

```
return View(emailcliklistreport.ToPagedList(pageIndex,pagesize);
```

it is not logic for me because I return list twice time

What do you recommend and suggest me to change my code.

How can I return linkler to view by casting ToPagedList ?

Comment: Why are you making linkler a pagedlist if you aren't returning it to the view? Keep it an IEnumerable and then return emailcliklistreport.ToPagedList(pageIndex,pagesize); to the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ToPagedList` should be the last operation your perform on your dataset before returning it to the view. As it stands, you're discarding the `PagedList` entirely and merely returning a `List<EmailLinkClickReport>` to the view.

Also, for what's worth, there's no need for a foreach loop here, anyways, as you can just use LINQ's `Select` method to transform your dataset. Try:

```
var linkler = mailingclickservice
    .GetByCriteria(x =>
        x.MailingID == ID &&
        x.Gonderim == gonderim &&
        x.Mailing.FirmUser.FirmID == FirmID)
    .IslemSonucu.GroupBy(x => x.MailingEmail)
    .Select(x => new EmailLinkClickReport
        {
            Key = x.Key;
            TotalClicksCount = x.Count();
        })
    .ToPagedList(pageIndex, pagesize);
```

*I added liberal spacing to make it easier to read. The only new part is the `Select` call. Also removed the `Select(x => x.MailingEmail)` jazz from `TotalClickCounts`, as it does nothing but just add extra processing time.*